Prove that this RSA based encryption scheme is not IND-CPA secure

It seems like c2 and c3 kinda reveal something but I cannot put my finger on how exactly we can get it.
Edit:

 I was confused about whether I can extract r from c3, but it seems like these Hash functions are invertible! (I missed that condition given in the task). Thanks for all comments.


What are $H_1$ and $H_2$?

We can assume $H_1$ and $H_2$ are public hashes with output in $\mathbb Z_n^*$. The exercise is about finding an adversary that wins the CPA experiment with non-vanishing advantage. Write down what that adversary must do. Hints: Your adversary can win with near certainty. You don't need to be much creative in how your adversary chooses it's messages, as any two distinct valid messages will do. Your adversary can make use of the public key. It can invoke $H_1$ and/or $H_2$. and one of the two is indispensable.

An adversary $\mathcal{A}$ can try to extract $m$ from $c_2$ letting him always win as long as his challenge uses two different $m, m'$.
To this end, he must get rid of $H_1(r)$.
Since $H_1, H_2$ and $n$ are public, knowing $r$ enables him to do so (as long as $\gcd(H_1(r), n) = 1$).
Can $\mathcal{A}$ extract $r$? The answer should be apparent given the ciphertext $(c_1, c_2, c_3)$.
Hint:

 Extract $r$ from $c_3$ in a similar fashion by eliminating $H_2(m)$.


There's an alternate, equally valid way to win the CPA experiment that does not use $c_2$.

what if gcd(H1(r),n) is not equal to 1). Then H1 or H2 woulnd't be invertible? Therefore, we won't able to extract r from c3?

@fgrieu is his explanation even true? And what other way is there? What would be the best/clearest proof

@fgrieu You're right. That's why $c_1$ is part of the ciphertext although it's not used anywhere.

@AyeLedder Yes, then $H_1(r)$ not invertible. But this cannot happen if we assume that the codomain of $H_1$ is $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$.

@AyeLedder Your question is obviously homework, intended to make you understand IND-CPA. Usually we only give hints on such questions (arLin went significantly past that). You can ask such question (and they can be answered), but you are expected to show your work, and where you are stuck. Here, you should at least edit the question to write down what the IND-CPA experiment is in your course (this varies slightly). You then should be able to turn this answer (which meat is correct) into a proof matching you course's convention.
